# Show username column instead of id in sfWidgetFormInputText

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, doctrine

This is probably an easy question but since I'm new with Symfony it's still a bit confusing.

I have a Podcast table which has a `user_id` column that is related to my `sfGuardUser` table which has an `id` column. (A user creates a podcast and his ID is saved automatically in the Podcast table, `creator_id` column)

Then, I have a PodcastForm where by default doctrine created this widget in the BasePodcastForm.class.php:

```
'creator_id' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('sfGuardUser'), 'add_empty' => false)),
```

Which creates a dropdown in the podcast form.

In my PodcastForm.php, I have:

```
    public function configure() {

        $this->widgetSchema['creator_id'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('readonly' => 'true'));

       ...
    }
```

But the problem is that it shows me the ID of the user instead of the name. In the sfGuardUser.class.php file I created the `__toString()` method returning the user's Username, but it stills shows the Id instead.

How could I do to show the Users' Username instead of the Id in the Podcast form as a `sfWidgetFormInputText`?

Comment: But if you save that you'll get an error as the form will use the username as a user id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope to understand well what you need... you could add as a new widget the username with a code like this:

```
public function configure()
{    
    $this->setWidget('creator_id', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
    if ($this->isNew())
    {
        $creator = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();
        $this->object->setCreatorId($creator->getId());
        $username = $creator->getUsername();
    }
    else
        $username = $this->object->getsfGuardUser()->getUsername();

    $this->setWidget('creator_name', new sfWidgetFormInput());
    $widget = $this->getWidget('creator_name');
    $widget->setDefault($username);
    $widget->setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    // if you need to move the widget use FIRST, LAST...
    $this->getWidgetSchema()->moveField('creator_name', sfWidgetFormSchema::FIRST);
    $this->setValidator('creator_name', new sfValidatorPass());
}
```

Maybe some adaptation is necessary because I use `Propel`.

Finally, it's a bad practice to use the singleton `sfContext::getInstance()->...` inside a form, but this is another matter.

**[update]** As Flukey said in his comment, just passing the user object through as a form option allows to remove the need for the sfContext singleton completely.

Comment: Pass the user object through as a form option and remove the need for the sfContext singleton completely.

Comment: @Flukey I wanted to focus my answer on how to display only the user name, which is the subject of the request, without enlarging too much the field of the response itself. Then I specified that using the singleton is a bad practice although I did not specified to pass the user object through as a form option. I really do not understand why you think my answer do not fit with the question.

Comment: where did i say  your answer does not fit with the question?

Comment: @Flukey Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Create or modify the `__toString()` method inside Podcast.class.php and add this:

```
public function __toString()
{
  return $this->getSfGuardUser()->getUsername();
}
```